# How do I add a namespace to all elements in a node?

Tags: xslt

Suppose I have some xml:

```
<a>
  <b>something</b>
  <c>something</c>
  <d>something</d>
</a>
```

and I want all children of `<a>` to be prefixed with the `x` namespace. Currently I have the following to achieve this:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <a>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
  </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <x:b><xsl:value-of select="." /></x:b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <x:c><xsl:value-of select="." /></x:c>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
  <x:d><xsl:value-of select="." /></x:d>
</xsl:template>
```

This works, but it is cumbersome and I have to know what all the children's names are. I am aware of the `match="*"` syntax but I don't know how to get the name of whatever `*` is so I can preface the `x` in the template match. Any ideas?

To be clear, I am hoping to replace those `xsl:template` nodes with a single node that will prefix whatever node name with one containing the `x` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:x="mynamespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="x:{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, @evil otto's (nice name!) solution is better than mine because `local-name()` is more suitable than `name()`. In your namespace configuration both solutions are equivalent, though.

Answer (score 2):

use `local-name(.)` to get the local name (i.e., the name without namespace) of a node, and `xsl:element` to create an element with that name.  Use `name(.)` for attributes.  Application is somthing like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:z="http://example.com/z">

 <xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:element name="z:{local-name(.)}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: add attribute template.