# How to add a namespace to each XML node with sed

Tags: xml, sed, xml-namespaces

Given the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response xmlns="...">
    <root>
        <test>abc</test>
    </root>
</response>
```

I need to add a namespace to each element like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns:response xmlns:ns="...">
    <ns:root>
        <ns:test>abc</ns:test>
    </ns:root>
</ns:response>
```

Is it possible with `sed`? I know `sed` is not the best tool for processing XML...

There could be nested nodes, but no one already has the namespace. Finally, there are no attributes.

Comment: It's hard to know without a more detailed specification of what you need to do - for the single example given, you could just use `s/test/ns:test/g` but I'm sure that's not what you're after.

Comment: I don't know the name of the nodes.... I just need a simple way to add a given namespace to all the nodes in a XML. The solution you suggest implies I know the tags...

Comment: My suggestion was a deliberate straw man to point out that *you haven't given us enough information*. Do you ever have two tags on the same line? Nested tags? Do the tags ever contain the string "ns:"? Do any of the tags *already* have namespace prefixes? Do any of them have attributes? Are any self-closing? All of these complexities could make some solutions invalid.

Comment: This might help: [How do I add a namespace to all elements in a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23923197/3776858)

Comment: OK, just update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a skinny description of the requirements, you can't do much more than this:

```
sed 's!</\|<!&ns:!g' your_file
```

The code

- uses `!` as a separator, so `/` needn't be escaped;
- the search string matches `</` or `<` via the alternation `\|`;
- the substitution consists of the matched piece itself, `&`, followed by `ns:`;
- all of this is done on the whole line via `g`.

In a comment you said you want to skip the submission on the line starting with `<?xml`, but changing the `s` command would just make it much longer and less readable.

Since that line is always and only the first, you can instead just target all lines except the first by prepending `2,$` to the `s` command.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for... Just need to skip the first line (`<?xml...`).